# Should I always use static factory methods instead of constructors?

Tags: java, oop

Reading Effective Java, it seems that there are many advantages, and very few disadvantages, to use static factory methods. By static factory methods I specifically mean the following

```
public class MyClass {    
  private MyClass() { ... };  

  public static MyClass getInstance() {
    return new A();
  }    
}
```

From Effective Java:

> Note that a static factory method is not the same as the Factory Method pattern from Design Patterns [Gamma95, p. 107]. The static factory method described in this item has no direct equivalent in Design Patterns.

Now is it best to always follow this practice, or only sometimes?

If so when?

Is is ever overkill to do this?

Comment: It's overkill when it's overkill. Only you can judge that. In general I would caution you against following *any* received wisdom blindly. You usually find that all the original qualifications with which the original statement was hedged about get forgotten, only the rule remains, often nobody really knows why.

Comment: In this case we are lucky since the original text is preserved in all its glory in Effective Java Item 1. But I'm not sure if my interpretation of this is correct.

Comment: I would say it is generally overkill unless you have a specific reason for wanting to hide the actual type being created, which is basically when you want to use a factory pattern. I suggest that in the majority of cases that isn't so. Consider what life would be like for example if you couldn't construct a String, or a Thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, constructors are simpler than Factories, so this is a major reason to choose constructors over Factory. Use Factory when the situation calls for it, no "by default". You should do the simplest thing that solves your problem, and most of the time this would be constructors.

Comment: I like your reasoning (Occam's razor), however I'm wondering if making the constructor public could come back to bite later on. Once its public it can no longer be made private without the risk of breaking existing code that has made use of the constructor. This means that retrofitting a static factory method later on may be painful. Also I guess there could be thread safety issues as well. I don't mean to question your answer, but I'm just wondering if there is more to it than this?

Comment: This is sort of a judgement call area, but a common problem is that developers tend to over-design their code. While it's true that you should think ahead, you should consider _how likely_ is it to require such a change. Then you have to make a judgement call. In general, I would still say that simpler is better. This is essentially an argument for YAGNI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain't_gonna_need_it

Comment: This is an excellent point. I'm wondering how to balance between avoiding overdesign on the one hand, and good encapsulation, that is, minimizing the accessibility of classes and members? That is, the constructor can always be made public, but once public it has to be public until the end of time.

Comment: It's difficult and I think it only comes with tons of experience. It really does depend on each individual case, and you'll need to analyze it as such. It goes back to how likely you think something will be needed. You should see how your "guesses" work out and adjust accordingly in the future.

Answer (score 2):

A factory approach abstracts the **Creation and Configuration** of objects from the code using the object.

If all depends the complexity involved in creation and initialization of object. If they are simple then no need to use factory pattern.

If its a bit complex (involving lot of steps in initialization before you use it) and better go with factory pattern.